# How to sync S3 buckets with different --endpoint-url

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

How can I sync two S3 buckets, if one is accessible with the `--endpoint-url`parameter, for instance `--endpoint-url=https://s4.us-east-2.stackpathstorage.com`, and the other is a normal S3 bucket (s3.amazonaws.com)?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Comment: @UmeshaD I studied the documentation thoroughly and didn't find an answer.

Comment: I didn't tried `aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2` it will sync 2 s3b buckets.

Comment: Your command syncs two buckets under the same Endpoint URL. That doesn't apply to my original question.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Use https://rclone.org/ tool. This is what you need.

1) **install rclone**

2) **configure two different S3 providers**

3) **check buckets**

```
$ sudo rclone lsd amazon-service:
```

Output: -1 2020-02-10 20:22:24        -1 bucket-one

```
$ sudo rclone lsd non-amazon-service:
```

Output: -1 2020-02-10 20:22:24        -1 bucket-two

4) **sync**

`$ sudo rclone sync amazon-service:bucket-one non-amazon-service:bucket-two`